# Interpolation Scheme Between a set of Quaternions

Tags: interpolation, quaternions, octonions

My question is similar to [Quaternion barycentric interpolation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418325/quaternion-barycentric-interpolation), but since that question is 6+ years old, I figured it could be asked again. I also will eventually be trying to do this with unit octonions (essentially replace every usage of quaternion with an octonion), but I think starting with the better known quaternion is best.

I have a set of $N$ unit quaternions, $Q = {q_0, q_1, ... q_N}$, and a test quaternion, $q_t$. For each quaternion in $Q$, there is an associated scalar value, $v_0 ... v_N$. I want to find an appropriate value for the test point, $v_t$, which is an interpolation between the nearest quaternions in $Q$ to $q_t$.

I recognize this question has multiple parts, and help on any part of would be beneficial. I have found solutions that would work in a euclidian space, but the fact that the unit quaternions all "live" on a hypersphere has been confusing me. The parts that I can think of are:

1. How can I find an appropriate set of the 4 nearest quaternions in $Q$? (If the space were euclidean, I would probably mesh $Q$ using a delaunay triangulation and find the tetrahedron surrounding $q_t$, but I'm not sure if this valid for quaternions on the 3-sphere)
2. How can I interpolate between those 4 quaternions to obtain the test value $v_t$? (In euclidean space you can use the barycentric coordinates, but I don't think that is defined for points on a hypersphere. My thought is to do something similar to the linear interpolation in [interpolation between 3 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163675/interpolation-between-3-points), but I am not sure if it is valid for quaternions)

Hopefully that makes sense, thank you.